# Joining two PostgreSQL tables that have a Nested field type " Record"in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

A postrgres app  has two tables ( PostgreSQL )

1. Orders

including field like:

- id
- Date
- Customer_id:
- Options_id

etc...

2. Options

including field like:

- id
- Name_of_Option

etc...

But , in the table "Orders" the Options_id field type is " Record". Has a nested value.

[image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2i9h.png)

When trying to do the join in Big Query

```
ON Orders.options_id = Options.id
```

I have this error:

> "Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT>"

What is the problem? I guess is because options_id is nested and the join is not working.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't get it.  Your image doesn't show a column called `meal_id`.

Comment: Gordon, you are correct. I edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks for the suggestion.